# "ResourceNotFoundError" when publishing react-native app to expo.io

Tags: react-native, expo

I've got two mobile apps I'm trying to publish.  The first one was very easy:

`$ expo publish`

However, the second one is showing me an error that I can't make sense of:

```
$ cd ~/sites/cvoeo-app
$ expo publish
There is a new version of expo-cli available (2.6.0).
You are currently using expo-cli 2.2.4
Run `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version
[12:59:51] Publishing to channel 'default'...
[12:59:54] Building iOS bundle
[12:59:54] 404 - "{\"type\":\"ResourceNotFoundError\",\"errors\":[],\"message\":\"The resource `/Users/micah/sites/fun-food-friends/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js` was not found.\"}"
[12:59:54] StatusCodeError: 404 - "{\"type\":\"ResourceNotFoundError\",\"errors\":[],\"message\":\"The resource `/Users/micah/sites/fun-food-friends/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js` was not found.\"}"
    at new StatusCodeError (/Users/micah/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/Users/micah/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/Users/micah/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/micah/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/micah/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/micah/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
```

The app I'm trying to publish is my "cvoeo-app".

However, the debug messages show that expo is complaining about a missing resource from a totally different project, the "fun-food-friends" app. I accidentally created a react native app in this directory, deleted it, and recreated a React JS app there with the same name.

It doesn't surprise me expo can't find the fun-food-friends file - but I'm very surprised that expo is even trying to look for it.  Why would it be looking for a resource in a totally different directory tree and project?

Comment: I do see "yarn" and "global" mentioned in the stacktrace a lot, but don't see why that would be a problem....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was, but the solution was kinda simple:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json yarn.lock
$ npm install
```

After that I was able to publish to expo without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

React native runs a server in a separate terminal window.

Since you ran the previous app and didn't close the terminal window opened while running the previous app, when you ran the new app, react-native didn't open a new terminal window to create a new server (since one is already running) and the new app on your device is still talking to the old server which was trying to serve your old deleted app.

Hence you got the "ResourceNotFound" error.

The solution is simply closing your old terminal and running your new app again.